# LINQ Query Sum in recordset

Tags: c#, linq

I am stuck on how to total a sum within a query.  Here's the code:

```
public ActionResult GetCommissionSummary(string agencyId, string month, string year)
{
     try
     {
         var as400rep = new iSeriesRepository(new iSeriesContext());
         var results = as400rep.GetCommissionSummary(agencyId, month, year).ToList();
         var CollectionSummary = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CommissionSummary>, IEnumerable<CommissionSummaryViewModel>>(results);
         var vm = new CommissionSummaryViewModel
         {
             Month = month,
             Year = year,
             CommissionSummary = CollectionSummary,
             CommissionsGrandTotal = results.Sum(x => decimal.Parse(x.CommissionAmount))
         };
         return PartialView("~/Areas/Insurance/Views/AgencyManagement/_CommissionSummary.cshtml", vm);
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         Log.Error(ex.Message, ex.InnerException);
            throw;
     }
}
```

I figured out how to get the grand total, pretty simple, but now I also need to get a sum by Policy (which is one of the fields that comes back in the results.  Can't find an example that's simple enough to follow.

Comment: are `PolicyTotal and CommissionsGrandTotal` the same thing..? you say your figred out how to get one but not the other but the code looks to be using the same code 
`PolicyTotal = results.Sum(x => decimal.Parse(x.CommissionAmount)),
CommissionsGrandTotal = results.Sum(x => decimal.Parse(x.CommissionAmount))` also don't use throw to show the exception use something like `Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);` or show in a MessageBox the `ex.Message`

Comment: Sorry, i included the policy total line accidentally.  Was a copy I forgot to take out.

Comment: So, do you want a dictionary of policy, sumOfCommissionAmount or do you just need to filter results based on a particular policy and get the subtotal within that policy?

Comment: So I need to get the line by line rows, then a total by policy, then the total amount for the whole recordset.  The total by policy is something that got added after everything else was done, and working.

Comment: May you post the data you are trying to sum and the results you are expecting?

Comment: So the "line by line rows" will have some with policy a, some with policy b, some with policy c, and you want your ViewModel to have a list of policies (a, b, c) and a sum total for reach?

Comment: I am sure you need to use Linq's group by to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm hoping the following example will help.  It shows using GroupBy along with creating a sub-totals by group.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        enum Policy
        {
            A, B, C
        }

        struct Row
        {
            public Policy p;
            public int commission;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const int MAX = 100;

            List<Row> rows = new List<Row>(MAX);
            Random rand = new Random(0);
            for (int x=0; x < MAX; x++)
            {
                int policy = rand.Next(3);
                int comm = rand.Next(1000);

                rows.Add(new Row() { p = (Policy)policy, commission = comm });
            }

            var query = rows.GroupBy(row => row.p, (policy, r) => new { Policy = policy, Sum = r.Sum(t => t.commission) });

            foreach(var result in query)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(result.Policy + ": " + result.Sum);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```